How to expand the telegram web application to the top using window.Telegram.WebApp.expand(); in html
How to expand the telegram web application to the top using window.Telegram.WebApp.expand(); in html
, here is an example of my code, but nothing works
<html>
<head>
    
    <script>
    window.Telegram.WebApp.ready();
    window.Telegram.WebApp.expand();
    </script>
    
    
</head>

I don't know if I'm using window.Telegram incorrectly.WebApp.expand();
I'm just a beginner

Have you imported the WebApp script?
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>

if yes try this way
<script>
    window.Telegram.WebApp.ready(function() {
        window.Telegram.WebApp.expand();
    });
</script>

